# Mounting ConfigMap to Airflow Worker Pod with KubernetesExecutor

Tags: airflow, kubernetes-helm, configmap, kubernetesexecutor

I have a scenario where I want to use Helm to deploy per environment Airflow configurations that use the KubernetesExecutor.

The issue I am running into is I need to the Scheduler mount per environment ConfigMaps in the Worker Pods when the KubernetesExecutor spawns them.

I have those ConfigMaps mounted fine in the Web and Scheduler pods, but I don't see a means to tell the KubernetesExecutor to mount specific ConfigMaps.

I don't see anywhere in the documentation how to do this, but I can't be the only one who wants their Docker Images to be environment agnostic and abstract everything away to the Helm level.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe the easiest way to do this is by specifying the `env_from_configmap_ref` setting in your `airflow.cfg` as described [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/configurations-ref.html#env-from-configmap-ref). If the configmaps are the same name in your different environments, this should be quite straight forward, e.g.

```
[kubernetes]
...
env_from_configmap_ref = <your-airflow-configmap>
...
```

If you have configmaps with different names in different environments (and can't make naming consistent), then you may need to specify the `airflow.cfg` in a configmap itself like in [this](https://github.com/astronomer/airflow-chart/blob/master/templates/configmap.yaml) example.

Comment: This is not what I am after. In my case, I want to mount files from a ConfigMap, not set Environment Variables.